# how to convert buffer read from sqlite3 to bitarrary

Tags: python, sqlite, bitarray

code:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
import sqlite3

a  = bitarray('1001011')

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
# conn = sqlite3.connect('tmp.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER, x BLOB)")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO t values (?, ?)", (1, sqlite3.Binary(a.tobytes())))
cursor.execute("select * from t")

rec = cursor.fetchone()

conn.commit()
conn.close()

b = bitarray.frombytes(rec[1])
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
18 conn.close()
19
---> 20 b = bitarray.frombytes(rec[1])

TypeError: descriptor 'frombytes' requires a 'bitarray._bitarray' object but received a 'buffer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured out

```
 aa = bitarray()
 aa.frombytes(str(rec[1]))
 print aa
 # bitarray('10010110')
 # Please pay attention to the size, the original bitarray is 1001011,
 # but str convert it to bytes by appending a zero
```

Comment: Alexander: This is the answer to his own question.